# help to write the Mathematica or Maple code for $\log(1+x)$ as MeijerG

Tags: special-functions, matlab, mathematica, maple

I am having difficulties working with some integral and I believe that if the natural logarithm in that integral is converted to its MeijerG equivalent, then it will be solved easily.

can somebody help me to write the MeijerG code for Maple, Mathematica or Matlab that is equivalent to $\ln(1+x)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeijerG.html

Comment: @Amzoti: Does Mathematica have the conversion command?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: They provide some complex examples here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html and reference http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/2881246826/ref=nosim/weisstein-20 for 2000 such cases. Lastly, you can see the settings for $\ln(x+1)$ here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function. Regards

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: You can also see over 1000 formulas here: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/03/23/

Comment: @Amzoti: My question is do they have a convert command just like in Maple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Maple:

```
[> convert(ln(1+x),MeijerG,include=elementary);
```

> $$xG^{1, 2}_{2, 2}\left(x\, \Big\vert\,^{0, 0}_{0, -1}\right)$$

Comment: Excuse me. Are my eyes working OK? What is this notation called? what are subscripts, superscripts, the numbers after '|' called?

Comment: That's how Maple renders it in Latex, or in the Extended typesetting mode.  In "Standard" mode it is
x*MeijerG([[0, 0], []], [[0], [-1]], x)